# How to get information in core handler program

Tags: python, linux, coredump

I went through [Naming of core dump files](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html)

this document says how to get the process id, hostname etc. This works pretty well if configured like :

```
echo "|/var/core_interceptor/bin/hello %P %u %g %s %t %c %e %h %d %E %i %p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

OR

```
echo "|/var/core_interceptor/bin/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %e %h %d %E %i %p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 


#include <stdio.h>
#define FILE_NAME "/var/core_interceptor/bin/text.txt"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i = 0;
   FILE* file_ptr = fopen(FILE_NAME, "w");
   for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
     fprintf(file_ptr, "\n%s", argv[i]);
   fclose(file_ptr);
   return 0;
}
```

This `hello.c` is not doing anything other than writing it to a text file. And when I see the generated file I see all the args with value i.e. I see actual PID etc.

But, when I configure a python program like this :

```
echo "|/var/core_interceptor/bin/pyhandler.py %P %u %g %s %t %c %e %h %d %E %i %p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

I don't get any of the args in the created file.

```
$ cat pyhandler.py 
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
f = open("/var/core_interceptor/bin/text1.txt", "w")
f.write("Called")
f.write(sys.argv[0:])
f.close()
```

this py script is getting called but does not print the args:

```
$ cat text1.txt 
Called
```

Why can I get the args in C program but not in python?

Answer (score 1):

You've probably figured this out already but your program is most likely throwing an exception because you are giving an argument of type list to a method that expects type str.

Sample program:

```
cat arg_writer.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import sys

with open("/tmp/output.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(sys.argv[0:])
```

Execution:

```
./arg_writer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./arg_writer.py", line 6, in <module>
    output.write(sys.argv[0:])
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list
[crknight@tbs5g-dev-san-02 tmp]$
```

If you force the list into a string form before writing you'll probably get what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import sys

with open("/tmp/output.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(sys.argv[0:]))
```

Example output:

```
cat /tmp/output.txt
['./arg_writer.py']
```